# Dynamically add/remove the same xml view

Tags: android, layout, addition, removechild, dynamic-view

I'm trying to toggle between adding and removing the same linearLayout view from my fragment. Everytime I add the line of code:

```
    ((ViewGroup)indexLayout.getParent()).removeView(indexLayout)
```

I get a null pointer exception, even when trying to add the view back...

OfflineFragment.java

```
private void displayIndex() {

     indexLayout = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.side_index);

        List<String> indexList = new ArrayList<>(mapIndex.keySet());

        TextView textView;

        for (String index : indexList) {
            textView = (TextView) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alphabet_indicator, null);
            textView.setText(index);
            textView.setOnClickListener(this);
            indexLayout.addView(textView);
        }
}

private void showDialog() {
    Dialog deleteDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).setTitle("Warning:")
            .setMessage("Are you sure that you want to delete all offline contacts?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                            //Delete cached data from internal storage and clear data structures
                            File dir = getActivity().getFilesDir();
                            File file = new File(dir, "cached.txt");
                            boolean deleted = file.delete();
                            System.out.println(deleted);
                            listView.setAdapter(null);
                            cachedSearch.clear();
                            l.clear();
                            mapIndex.clear();
                            sections = null;
                            names = null;
                           ((ViewGroup)indexLayout.getParent()).removeView(indexLayout)

                        }
                    }
            )
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    }
            ).create();
    deleteDialog.show();
}
```

Stack Trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.LinearLayout.addView(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
                                                                                    at com.fil.uk.mobile.fidelitycontacts.Fragments.OfflineFragment$override.displayIndex(OfflineFragment.java:122)
                                                                                    at com.fil.uk.mobile.fidelitycontacts.Fragments.OfflineFragment$override.refreshData(OfflineFragment.java:215)
                                                                                    at com.fil.uk.mobile.fidelitycontacts.Fragments.OfflineFragment$override.access$dispatch(OfflineFragment.java)
                                                                                    at com.fil.uk.mobile.fidelitycontacts.Fragments.OfflineFragment.refreshData(OfflineFragment.java:0)
                                                                                    at com.fil.uk.mobile.fidelitycontacts.CarouselFragment.refreshData(CarouselFragment.java:215)
                                                                                    at com.fil.uk.mobile.fidelitycontacts.MainActivity.update(MainActivity.java:120)
                                                                                    at com.fil.uk.mobile.fidelitycontacts.Fragments.SearchResultFragment.refreshData(SearchResultFragment.java:212)
                                                                                    at com.fil.uk.mobile.fidelitycontacts.Fragments.SearchResultFragment.onCreateView(SearchResultFragment.java:105)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2074)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1286)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:758)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1671)
                                                                                    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:532)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Comment: provide the stacktrace for exception!

Comment: @Jordan done mate!

Comment: are you sure you have a LinearLayout in your xml with id R.id.side_index?

Comment: Also where's v coming  from in displayIndex()?

Comment: @Jordan yes. It loads fine when the fragment is first initiated, the only problem comes when I try to add the view back to the layout, after removing it in the method - showDialog

Comment: @Jordan v is the field variable of type View that is used to inflate the xml layout "offline_frag" in my onCreateView method

Comment: Well you have answered it yourself in your comment! Look what you just wrote "the only problem comes when I try to add the view back to the layout, AFTER REMOVING IT in the method". So the view doesn't exist anymore once you remove it. You have to create a new view and add it rather than trying to inflate it again from xml!

Comment: @Jordan yes that's correct so you can't inflate xml more than once?

Comment: well! what sushant said in the answer below :)

Comment: There is one more thing here! Why would you add and remove this view again and again? Can't you simply hide it and then make it visible again when needed?

Comment: Also you should mark something as answer if it's correct! :)

Comment: @Jordan I need to remove the view because the textviews are added conditionally depending on the contents of the List<> indexList

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove view

```
 ((ViewGroup)indexLayout.getParent()).removeView(indexLayout)
```

Than you cant get it back !! you have to add it agin if you want to use it

Try to add View if null

```
private void displayIndex() {

     indexLayout = (LinearLayout)v.findViewById(R.id.side_index);

      if(indexLayout==null){
          LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(getContext().LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
          View mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_view_having_indexLayout , null, false);
          indexLayout =(LinearLayout)mView.findViewById(R.id.side_index);
      }  
        List<String> indexList = new ArrayList<>(mapIndex.keySet());

        TextView textView;

        for (String index : indexList) {
            textView = (TextView) getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alphabet_indicator, null);
            textView.setText(index);
            textView.setOnClickListener(this);
            indexLayout.addView(textView);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @Sushant, I'm no longer receiving the null pointer exception... but the textviews are no longer showing. I'll figure this one out